# filter data multiple dropdown google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-query-language

I am trying to filter data from my google sheed with multiple dropdowns 
my spredsheet looks like this:
[image]

I have 2 tabs. tab 1 has all by info and tab 2 is where i am trying to filter data.
I would like to have dropdowns above age, book 1 and book 2 to filter these options but when i do this it will not disply all eg. if i only want to find people who have finished book 1 i dont want to apply a filter to the other dropdowns.

```
=query(tab1!A:D, " select * where B = '"&B2&"' AND C = '"&C2&"' " AND D = '"&D2&"' "  )
```

Comment: Screenshot of tab 1 and link your spreadsheet or a dummy copy of it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` looks whether it is exactly equal. Since B2/C2/D2 is blank, it'll filter all conditions and then provide the filtered data. You might wanna use `matches` or `contains`.

```
  =QUERY(tab1!A:D, " select * where B contains '"&B2&"' AND C contains '"&C2&"' AND D contains '"&D2&"' "  )
```

There was also an extra `"` in your formula.